# Excel VBA: Making New Sheets From a Shared Column Value

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

As a duty as work, I was told to open a spreadsheet in Excel 2003 (getting a newer computer soon...), and split the one sheet into a document with many worksheets based off of one ID: Vendor Id #.

Worksheet has a one-row-high header. The first Header column is "VendorID". Now, there are DOZENS of other headers for each column here, and they contain **equations**. I want the sheets to be the name of the vendor ID.

What I want is to get many sheets like so:

A sheet called "00708", the A-column header of "vendorId", which contains:

```
vendid |  B   |  C   |  D   |
00708  | true | 1.07 | 4.52 |
```

Just an example. There are MANY columns of different info. Many.

My problem is that, at work, I tried this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistributeRows()
Dim wsAll As Worksheet
Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowCrit As Long
Dim I As Long


Set wsAll = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change All to the name of the worksheet the existing data is on

LastRow = wsAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

' column A has the criteria eg project ref
wsAll.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

LastRowCrit = wsCrit.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To LastRowCrit

    Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
    wsNew.Name = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    wsAll.Rows("1:" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
     CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
    wsCrit.Rows(2).Delete

Next I

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsCrit.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The problem is that this code worked BEAUTIFULLY....up until I scrolled more to the right and realized that many of the columns, while still appropriately moved, contained blank spaces where not only numbers used to be, but also numbers that are factored though Excel equations (adding values from cells next to them, that sort of thing)

So basically....is there not a definitive code for this? I searched the web for hours but any code I tried would give me errors that I'm sorry to have not remembered so I could tell you. I'm pretty sure the code above was the one that worked, but it emitted **vital** information and equations and made them blank.

I have ~8000 rows and know excel can do something like 65,000 rows. I've seen some code that tries to grab corner-to-corner regions, but I don't need that. I need a code that grabs every column and every row...looks at the first value of the first 'type' of info (in this case, Vendor ID), and then creates as many new sheets (in this same document) as it needs to to create one for every single different vendor ID.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm trying to not have to do this by hand as much as possible.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of VBA at all or are you just looking for code to copy-paste ?

Comment: I've programmed in the past, not VBA, and so I like to think I could understand this code by reading it, but can't create it on my own.

Comment: Why not record a Macro of what you would do manually (to overlook the emtpy cells eg `string.IsNullOrEmtpy(Range[top + left].Value2)') - then stop recording the Macro - Alt + F11 and look at the generated VBA code. If you've programmed in the past it should be easy to skill yourself up in VBA using this method - admittedly it will be procedural spagetti code but you can fix that up using If, Loops & etc

Comment: Your help is appreciated but unfortunately I am too unskilled to try and write it myself

Comment: Jeremy made a good point, record a Macro of what you want to do, and it will write the VBA for you.